# Controller's listeners catching events (panel clicks) from other views

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have this weird issue with ExtJS 4.2.1.

I have a controller whose listeners catch events from a view that it shouldn't.

Here's said controller:

```
Ext.define('Customer_Portal_UI.controller.NavigationMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'panel': {
                render: function (panel) {
                    panel.body.on('click', function (panel, e) {
                        alert('onclick');
                    });
                }
            }


        });

    }
});
```

It 'controls' this view:

```
Ext.define('Customer_Portal_UI.view.NavigationMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.navigationmenu',
    region: 'west',
    layout: 'fit',
    ui: 'cssmenu',
    loader: {
        autoLoad: true,
        url: '/resources/notloggedin.html'
    }

});
```

But it also catches panel clicks from this view:

```
Ext.define("Customer_Portal_UI.view.MainContent", {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.maincontent',
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'card',
    border: false,
    activeItem: 0,
    requires: ['Ext.grid.Panel'],
    initComponent: function () {

        this.items = [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    title: ''
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                    id: 'contactlistgrid',
                                    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('contactStore'),
                                    columns: [
                    ....
                                    ],
                                    features: [{
                                        ftype: 'grouping',
                                        groupHeaderTpl: ['{columnName}: {name} - ({rows.length} employees)'],
                                        hideGroupedHeader: true,
                                        startCollapsed: false
                                    }],
                                    viewConfig: { id: 'contactlistgridview' }
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'gridpanel',
                                    id: 'caselistgrid',
                                    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('caseStore'),
                                    columns: [
                                                { text: 'Title', dataIndex: 'title' },
                                                { text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'description' },
                                                { text: 'Ticket number', dataIndex: 'ticketnumber' }
                                    ],
                                    viewConfig: { id: 'caselistgridview' }
                                }
                ]


        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Do you see any obvious reasons why it would do this ? `panel` is indeed the panel I'm clicking and not the document body, which could have explained why.

Note that's in not catching clicks from other panels, just from the `MainContent` view, which it should not...

Thanks.

Comment: Your selector says `panel`, which means it's going to match every component that is a panel (or subclass). You need to refine your selectors to only match the relevant things.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Thanks for your comment, found a fix.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I don't understand why the controller would catch events from 'panel' from other views. Are controllers by design doing this and we simply separate the logic in different physical controller files only for organisation purposes ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was two fold as shown in here:

http://www.fusioncube.net/index.php/sencha-extjs-4-make-any-component-fire-a-click-event/comment-page-1

Then I was able to listen to 'click' for 'panel' (there's only one panel within the view) within my controller without having to refine my selector.